# Upload File to the Telegram

Tags: c#, telegram

How to send a file into the telegram api in C# and getting a file_id to reference?

the question is *how can I upload a file to the telegram server through a C# code?*

I found [this](https://core.telegram.org/api/files) in telegram api, but I cannot understand the syntax.

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/api/ is **NOT** the telegram Bot-Api

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu I am seeking around sending media to the bot, it is not about how can I received data in bot side. Indeed, as mentioned in question, I wanna send data to the bot, but not through the telegram app, through an endpoint. Could you reference to any example to send data to the bot through a C# code?

Comment: @tashakori you can see the above comment! receiving the data in bot side is not my question.

Comment: Just to be clear  you are saying you want send file to your bot and also on telegram server right?  Get the file id and forward the file to some another user? You want the file_id to work with?

Comment: @newuser exactly. in a simple case, I want to send a file to the telegram server, and then use the returned file_id in the bot to send it into the other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The referenced link is in [TL language](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/TL).
I have implemented a sample to find file_id and send it to a specified user in C# using TLSharp:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TeleSharp.TL;
using TLSharp.Core;
using TLSharp.Core.Utils;
namespace TLSharpTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(async () => { await doTask(); });
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static async Task doTask()
        {
            var apiId = 87654321; //apiId: get from https://my.telegram.org/apps
            var apiHash = "<apiHash>"; // get from https://my.telegram.org/apps
            var client = new TelegramClient(apiId, apiHash);
            await client.ConnectAsync();

            var phone = "<phone_number>";
            var hash = await client.SendCodeRequestAsync(phone);
            var code = "<sent_code_by_telegram>";
            var user = await client.MakeAuthAsync(phone, hash, code);

            //get available contacts
            var result = await client.GetContactsAsync();    
            //find recipient in contacts
            var specifiedUser = result.users.lists
                    .Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(TLUser))
                    .Cast<TLUser>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.phone == "<recipient_phone>");
            // send file to the specified contact (sample from TLSharp github)
            var fileResult = (TLInputFile)await client.UploadFile("cat.jpg", new StreamReader("data/cat.jpg"));
            await client.SendUploadedPhoto(new TLInputPeerUser() { user_id = specifiedUser.id }, fileResult, "kitty");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `UploadFile` method is not awailable now in this library

Answer (score 0):

**you have two options**

1. Yo can use telegram bot api which you can find in [this](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples) page,  there is a method to send file that called `sendDocument` which is all explained [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputfile) and this method gives you file_id after uploaded. But there is some limitations about how long the file will last or what kind of files you can send and what size is acceptable.
2. You can use telegram it self instead of using bot api which means you have to sign-up with number like a regular telegram user to send and receive file. There is c# library and also telegram open source for Windows phone which is c# you can dig into it and manage it for uploading files and get file id for your bot or just send the file directly to your bot from that acount.

[this is list of all telegram open source app (not bot api)](https://telegram.org/apps#telegram-for-wp)

Use "mtproto telegram c#" for google to get repository for c# mtproto library. 
The good library that can handle easy your need is [TLShorp](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp) (wich needs phone number to work obviously)

Comment: Thanks. I did that by TLSharp. But, the question is how can do the same for bot.

Comment: @OmG use sendDocument to upload file on telegram server and get file_id,  if you have file_id just send it,  you have to read the bot api document to learn it, there is a lot bot api in c# that have method to send file by giving the file bytes or file path it will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

```
using TLSharp.Core.Utils;
```

- 

```
var file = (TLInputFile)(await this.Client.UploadFile(FileName, new StreamReader(FilePath)));
return file.Id;
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained *why* it answers the question and how it improves existing answers instead of having to infer it from the code.